# Почему здесь password_verify всё время возвращает false?

Tags: php, mysql

К базе подсоединяется всё нормально забирает пароль, но пишет, что пароль не правильный

```html
$login=$_POST['login'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    
    $login=mb_strtolower($login);
    
    $login=trim($login);
    $password=trim($password);
    $login=htmlspecialchars($login);
   // mysql_select_db('makinson_h',$mysqli);
 $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `REG` WHERE `login`='$login'");/*обьект*/
    $result=$result->fetch_assoc();/*массив*/
 $hash = $result['password'];
 
   if(password_verify($password,$hash))   {
    echo 'Пароль правильный!';
} else {
    echo 'Пароль неправильный.';
}
```

Vardamp $hash возвращает хэш всё как надо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы хешировали? Сравните пароль и хеш при хешировании и при проверке.

Comment: в другом файле $password=password_hash(password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(12));

Comment: Что за array(12)?

Comment: Всё работает http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/300d0813898ee0110974582cd73d50bdd14e8f2b. У вас, значит, пароли или хеши не совпадают, которые вы подаёте на вход. При хешировании пароля вы делаете trim()? Повторюсь, выведите пароли и хеши и сравните их.

Comment: да, при хэшировании пароля делаю трим

Comment: хэш пароля в базе и хэш пароля в этом фале отличаются, теперь бы понять почему